# bean validation spring + hibernate annotion does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

What am I doing wrong? The test does not work.

This is my Interface class:

```
@Validated
public interface ICustomerService
{
    public List<Customer> findbyStr(
    @NotEmpty(message = "{column.notvalid}")
    @NotNull(message = "{column.notvalid}")
    String column,
    @NotEmpty(message = "{column.notvalid}")
    @NotNull(message = "{value.notvalid}")
    String value);
}
```

This is my Implementation class:

```
@Service("customerService")
@Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CustomerService implements ICustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private IStorageDao<Customer> dao;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findbyStr(String column, String value) {
        return dao.findByString(Customer.class, column, value);
    }

}
```

This is my unit-Test class:
JUNIT Test does not work.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CustomerTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private ICustomerService service;
    @Autowired
    public static Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void test_A6_CustomerFindByStrNull() {
        List<Customer> result = service.findbyStr(null, null);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<ICustomerService>> constraintViolations = validator
                .validate(service);

        assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size());
        assertEquals("Die angegebene E-Mail-Adresse ist fehlerhaft.",
                constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertNotNull(result.get(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It needs to get a error message and that does not happen

Comment: sorry I mistyped me, its 
`assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
  assertEquals("Die angegebene E-Mail-Adresse ist fehlerhaft.",
    constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());`

Comment: `finally assertThat(result, is(nullValue()));`

Comment: `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<0> at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88) at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot test `ConstraintViolations` when the annotations are on a method of an object since it should throw a `MethodConstraintViolationException`. You should try something like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CustomerTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ICustomerService service;

    @Test
    public void test_A6_CustomerFindByStrNull() {
        try {
            List<Customer> result = service.findbyStr(null, null);
        } catch (MethodConstraintViolationException ex) {
            assertEquals("Die angegebene E-Mail-Adresse ist fehlerhaft.", ex.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next().getMessage());
        }
        fail("Exception expected");
    }
}
```

You need to have the following Bean in your `application-context.xml` file :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: You are right I also found this solution on the internet but I can not find the class `MethodConstraintViolationException` in hibernate-validator Version 5.0.1.Final

Comment: `MethodConstraintViolationException cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: It seem that Hibernate 5+ support will only be added in Spring 4. It only works with the 4.x version of hibernate validator

Comment: I just tried with version 4.3.1.final and has not found
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/method/MethodConstraintViolationException.html

Comment: It should work with the 4.3.1 : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/method/MethodConstraintViolationException.html

Comment: It doesn't find the class?

Comment: It is not in catch area 
`assertEquals("Die angegebene E-Mail-Adresse ist fehlerhaft.", ex
     .getConstraintViolations().iterator().next().getMessage());`

Comment: did you have <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/> in your application-context.xml?

Comment: Yes, java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to XXXX.Interface